# Not able to copy/paste from IntelliJ to Chrome in Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, intellij-idea, ubuntu-12.04, copy-paste

I'm running IntelliJ in Ubuntu 12.04 and if I copy from a file in IntelliJ am unable to paste into Chrome. I'm aware of some subtleties around Ubuntu's clipboard, but am able to copy/paste from IntelliJ to Text Editor without an issue. Would anyone be able to advise on this?